# CursorAdapter updating the list in a wierd manner

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I am using StickyListHeaders library with Cursor Adapter and I am facing a very strange issue. 
When I scroll down the list and when I scroll back, the first List item is having the correct data, but half of the data is incorrect. Here is the code and let me explain a little more.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MergeCursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter;

public class BookingAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

    MergeCursor c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;

    public BookingAdapter(Context context, MergeCursor c) {
        super(context, c, true);
        this.c = c;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_card, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final String tempname, tempnumber;
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views
        Button cancelBooking = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.cancelbooking);
        Button driverInfo = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.driverinfo);
        TextView bookindId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookingID);
        TextView historyFrom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyFrom);
        TextView historyTo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyTo);
        TextView historyDateTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyDateTime);
        TextView historyStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyStatus);
        bookindId.setText("Booking ID: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));
        historyFrom.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
        historyTo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));
        historyDateTime.setText("Booking at " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(7))) + " on " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(6))) + ".");
        historyStatus.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))));

        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))).equals("Confirmed")) {
            driverInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historyStatus.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.confirmed));
            tempname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(9)));
            tempnumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(8)));
            driverInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //figure out a way to create a dialog fragment from here
                }
            });
        } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))).equals("Cancelled")){
            cancelBooking.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            driverInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            historyStatus.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.alert));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, viewGroup, false);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //set header text as first char in name
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        String headerText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(10)));
        holder.text.setText(headerText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return c.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int i) {
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(10))).equals("Confirmed")) {
            return 2;
        } else if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(10))).equals("Booked")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    class HeaderViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}
```

So when I scroll back up, after going down

```
if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))).equals("Confirmed")) {
            driverInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historyStatus.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.confirmed));
            tempname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(9)));
            tempnumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(8)));
            driverInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //figure out a way to create a dialog fragment from here
                }
            });
```

This part is getting executed even though cursor.getString is not equal to "Confirmed". It's equal to "Booked"

.
.
Here are the screenshots.
Before Scrolling:

> [image]

After Scrolling down and scrolling back up:

> [image]

The driver info button and green status text should ideally show when the "status" in cursor is "Confirmed".
Please help.

Comment: does your column name is "Confirmed"?. see here cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))).equals("Confirmed")

Comment: Column name has three values... Either Confirmed or Cancelled or Booked... Only for Confirmed it should show "Driver info"  button.. Initially it is showing correctly but after scrolling back it is showing this way

Comment: i said you are comparing here columnName with "confirm", not with column value . check again.

Comment: cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(10))).equals("Confirmed")
column name is just being sent to getColumnIndex for getString. The comparison is with the value in the column. There is some problem with list items being out of the view.

Comment: Ok Guys I solved it using getItemViewType and using different inflated layout for all of them